# Homework help, what am I doing wrong here? [Javascript, validation]

Tags: javascript, forms, html, validation

Trying to get this form to validate email using the function the professor said to use. We cannot use jquery or any other way to handle this.  He's very...specific...on how he wants things done.  Anyway, last week of a web design course and introduces javascript without much explanation.

The function is simply validating email but I have no frickin clue on how to call the function properly (verify_email).  I've found countless examples of how to do this other ways but I'm pretty sure he will take off points for not doing it his way. Frantically trying to format this on an edit... it was fine when I submitted.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en-US">
 <head>
   <title>Feedback</title>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
   <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="media/css/webpageCSS.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery /1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  function verify_email ()
  {
      var email_val=document.getElementById("email").value;
  var regex = /^[A-Z0-9_%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;
  if( email_val.search( regex ) == -1)
  {
  alert("Email is not valid");
  return false;
  }
  else
  {
  return true;
  }
  }
 </script>


 </head>
 <body class="sdd">

  <nav>
    <a href="Project4.html">Home</a>
      &nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="resume.html">Resume</a>
      &nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="classList.html">Class List</a>
      &nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="misc.html">Miscellaneous</a>
      &nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="comments.html">Feedback</a>
  </nav>
    <header>
  <h1 class="sd">Feedback Page</h1> 
  </header>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="leftcolumn2">
        </div>
    <div id="rightcolumn2">
     <section>
     <br><br>
      Feedback Form:
    <form name="comform" method="post" action="http://webdevfoundations.net/scripts/formdemo.asp" onsubmit="return verify_email();">
        <table class="comtab">
            <tr>
                <td>*First Name: <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname"></td>
                <td>*Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname" id="flname"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="com" colspan="2"><textarea cols="60" rows=5 name="comments" id="comments">Enter your feedback here</textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="alignl" colspan="2">Email (optional): <input type="text" name="email" id="email"></td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="alignl" colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Submit Comment" ></td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </form>
    </section>

    <footer class="footbot">
  &copy; 2010
    </footer>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: If you can't use jQuery, why is it included?

Comment: For later use on as-of-yet unmade table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en-US">
 <head>
  <title>Feedback</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="media/css/webpageCSS.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

      <script type="text/javascript">
      function verify_email ()
      {
          var email_val=document.getElementById("email").value;
      var regex = /^[A-Z0-9_%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;
      if( email_val.search( regex ) == -1)
      {
      alert("Email is not valid");
      return false;
      }
      else
      {
      return true;
      }
      }
     </script>


    </head>
    <body class="sdd">

  <nav>
    <a href="Project4.html">Home</a>
          &nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="resume.html">Resume</a>
          &nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="classList.html">Class List</a>
          &nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="misc.html">Miscellaneous</a>
          &nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="comments.html">Feedback</a>
  </nav>
        <header>
  <h1 class="sd">Feedback Page</h1> 
  </header>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="leftcolumn2">
            </div>
        <div id="rightcolumn2">
        <section>
        <br><br>
        Feedback Form:
        <form name="comform" method="post" action="http://webdevfoundations.net/scripts/formdemo.asp" onsubmit="return verify_email();">
            <table class="comtab">
                <tr>
                    <td>*First Name: <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname"></td>
                    <td>*Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname" id="flname"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="com" colspan="2"><textarea cols="60" rows=5 name="comments" id="comments">Enter your feedback here</textarea></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="alignl" colspan="2">Email (optional): <input type="text" name="email" id="email"></td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="alignl" colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Submit Comment" ></td>
                </tr>

            </table>
        </form>
        </section>

        <footer class="footbot">
      &copy; 2010
        </footer>
        </div>
        </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This seems to work, now I have to study WHY.  Thanks so much, I will edit this in.

Comment: I frown upon copy/paste. If you don't know what's broken, try figuring it out. That's part of the learning process.

Comment: problem is in function verify_email (email_val),when you use email_val.search() this email_val doesn't contain any value,so firstly we have assign the value of email field in email_val then match it with regular expression

Comment: @Blender- I am going to study this vigorously.  And as for the trial and error/google/textbook method, 4 hours is my limit for one or two lines of code :/  I'm on hour 6 now.  I only come to SO when I'm about ready to drop from exhaustion.  Rest assured I WILL know this by the time I'm done.

Comment: or you can also use <input type="submit" value="Submit Comment" onclick="return verify_email(email.value);"> and use the function         <script type="text/javascript">
      function verify_email (email)
      {
      var regex = /^[A-Z0-9_%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;
      if( email.search( regex ) == -1)
      {
      alert("Email is not valid");
      return false;
      }
   else
   {
      return true;
   }
   }
     </script> its work

Comment: @Bhanu. Use inline code (it's the tilda or the button to the left of `1`), it makes it a lot easier to read.

Comment: @roger34, the other answers people gave here are all mostly true. Oh, and good luck! I remember when I was fiddling with CSS (no formal programming/design courses here, so :P)... It was horrid.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function verify_email (email_val)
  {
    var regex = /^[A-Z0-9_%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;
    if( email_val.search( regex ) == -1)
    {
      alert("Email is not valid");
      return false;
    }else{
      return true;
    }
  }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the body of your page you need to register the function with the input for the email.

```
<input type="text" name="email" onchange="verify_email()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be the problem:

```
function verify_email(email_val)
{
  var regex = /^[A-Z0-9_%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;

  if (email_val.search(regex) == -1)
  {
    alert("Email is not valid");
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

It will always return `true`. Also, `search` doesn't handle Regex. You need to run the string *onto* the regex. This code might work:

```
function verify_email(email_val)
{
  var regex = /^[A-Z0-9_%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;

  if (regex.exec(email_val) == -1)
  {
    alert("Email is not valid");
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Also, see the comment Matt Phillips posted: [Homework help, what am I doing wrong here? [Javascript, validation]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4446789/homework-help-what-am-i-doing-wrong-here-javascript-validation/4446822#4446822).

Also, `verify_email(email)` is not defined. You should use `verify_email(document.getElementById('email').value)`.

Comment: Adding the `else` statement changes nothing.  `return true` isn't executed when the `if` condition is true.

Comment: Isn't that the point? If the email is false, `verify_email` returns false. I would add an event variable in there, personally, so that I can stop the browser from submitting, but that's out of the scope of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting to pass the string "email" to the email validation function? Or do you want to actually check whatever is in the email `input`? If you're just passing "email" to test, it needs to be in quotes (`'`) for it to be passed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The javascript variable email is not defined anywhere so you are passing an undefined variable to the javascript function.  call the function like

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit Comment" onclick="verify_email(document.getElementById('email').value);">
```